# Managed windows service not starting every time

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have created a windows service, which does pretty much standard stuffs. OnStart method hosts a WCF service endpoint using ServiceHost class.

The problem I'm facing is that the service doesn't start every time windows starts, and sadly this behavior is intermittent, i.e, some times it does start on windows start-up. Thus, it seems the service configuration is not entirely wrong either.

After adding various logs in onstart method, it seems that the onstart method is also not being called at all when it service doesn't start. So, doesn't seem like some kind of failure during onstart method.

Can anyone suggest why this happens? Is it normal at all?

Thanks,
Nripendra

Comment: I haven't experience this problem, but I'd suggest putting some strategic error handling in your startup routine and maybe some System.Diagnostics.EventLog statements to see where things are failing.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have placed some logs and it seems the onstart function is never being called.

Comment: I'm not sure what your programming in, but there may be some events that precedes OnStart, like OnLoad or Initialize ... something like that.